# Product price is not set when programmatically creating quote

Tags: magento-1.9, database, price, quote

I am creating a rest api for cart.

```
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
 $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
 $quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
 $quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

Quote is generated as expected. The only issue is with price.
Item price is not set in `quote_item` table.
Also in quote tables `base_price`, `subtotal`, etc are not set.

Comment: Please try by setting store as $quote->setStoreId(1)->addProduct($product, $qty)

Comment: Still not working

Comment: can u please try $quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)->collectTotals()->save();

Comment: Same Issue exist.
I am trying to add products in cart. Billing and shipping address is not required at this point.
When product is added from website(frontend) and then add product to same quote from API, it is working as expected.
The only issue exist when quote is created from API.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

Changed following code to

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```

To

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$quote->addProduct($product, $qty);
$quote->setIsActive(false)->setIsMultiShipping(false);
$quote->getBillingAddress();
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
```